Error: "arguments imply differing number of rows: 223, 19" for a rectangle matrix with equal row lengths?
I am trying to produce an ordination plot from some community data. However, when I try turn the metaMDS object into a data frame and extract its scores so I can plot it I am met with the error:
Error in (function (..., row.names = NULL, check.rows = FALSE, check.names = TRUE,  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 223, 19

Here is my code:
   # Prepare the community matrix
    community_matrix <- data %>%
      select(`Codium dimorphum`:Caulacanthus) %>%
      as.matrix()

   # Prepare environmental data
    env_data <- data %>%
      select(Site, elevation, Expossure)

   # Perform NMDS
    community_matrix[is.na(community_matrix)] <- 0 
    community_matrix <- apply(community_matrix, 2, as.numeric)
    tot <- rowSums(community_matrix)
    community_matrix <- community_matrix[tot > 0, ] ####Had to do these 4 lines of code to be         able to use the metaMDS function in the next line####

    nmds <- metaMDS(community_matrix, distance = "bray", k = 2, trymax = 100)

   # Extract NMDS scores
    nmds_scores <- as.data.frame(scores(nmds)) ####This is where I get the error####

